# Can't download video from sandboxed iframe in IE11

Tags: javascript, iframe, sandbox

There is the issue in my application related to using iframe to embed a video.
The video has a download button to download the video. It works fine at all browsers except IE11.

I click to download button in video inside iframe. As a result the new tab opens and nothing happens.

We use SANDBOX attribute for this iframe and can't delete it according to our security policies.

```
sandbox='allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups allow-downloads'
```

Could somebody help to understand why it doesn't work on IE11 only? Are there any ways to fix the issue?

[Video in iframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X128y.jpg)

[Result of trying to download](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHHkx.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I assume because IE11 does not support the `allow-downloads` sandbox option, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Although I am able to show the download dialog in IE11 in a sandboxed iframe with navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);